# Passing array data to view from controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my controller function code:

```
         public function dispcp(){
            $data = array(
            'company' => $this->input->post("company"),
            'fyfrom' => $this->input->post("fyfrom"),
            'fyto' => $this->input->post("fyto"),
          );   

    $this->load->view('view',$data);
 }
```

> Here the data comes from a form from another view.

this is what my code in view.php looks like :
`<?php print_r ($data[0]->fyfrom); ?>`

Error:
Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/view.php

Line Number: 14

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\admin\application\views\view.php
Line: 14
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\admin\application\controllers\Dashboard.php
Line: 586
Function: view

File: C:\wamp\www\admin\index.php
Line: 263
Function: require_once

> Works correctly in Controller, not in view.

Comment: $data is what you named the payload in the controller, the name of variables aren't passed when you call a function.   The view will extract what you passed into their own variables, like in mrbm's answer.   You also have no 0 key and you're accessing an array like an object so  you have quite a few concerns in your attempt.  It might be better to do some more reading.

Comment: Remove the array reference of `[0]` in `view.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the data is passed to the view you need to use the array keys are variables directly :

```
<?php print_r($fyfrom); ?>
```

Comment: for example: `echo $company`

Comment: Worked very well
Thanks